# TensorFlow: Custom data type

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm interested in studying the effects of Fixed Point math on CNN using TensorFlow.
To the best of my knowledge, and what I've seen in the DTypes, fixed point isn't implemented.
Is there a guide to adding a new DType to tensorflow? I've been unable to find anything on the website or here.
Thanks,
Arik